# No result from "count down" loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am given a declaration such as this:

```
public String countDown(int start, int end, int increment)
```

I'm looking for an output that would give:

```
(10 8 6 4)
```

If `countDown` was called with `start = 10`, `end = 3` and `increment = 2`. It would keep decrementing 2 until it reaches the end.

I know how to construct the for loop, just have no idea how to get it to work with the string.

Here's what I have for code:

```
String countD = "";
for (int i = start; i <= end; i = i - increment) {
    countD = countD + i;
    countD = countD + " ";

}
return countD;
```

I'm assuming start is greater than end, and I've already taken care of the case when start = end. The problem I'm having is that countD is returning a blank string right now "<[]>", and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You can add to the string like `countD += i+" ";`

Comment: If start is superior than end, the condition of the loop should be `i >= end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set `i` to 10, and the loop condition is that `i` must be smaller or equal to `end`. `end` is set to 3. 10 is not smaller than 3 :)

An useful technique to debug things like this is to insert a print statement inside the loop, so that you can see that your code is actually executing. Something as simple as this for example:

```
for (int i = start; i <= end; i = i - increment) {
            System.out.println("In the loop!");
            countD = countD + i;
            countD = countD + " ";
            System.out.println(countD);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is an error with the logic of your loop. If start is greater than end, you should have `i >= end`, instead of `i <= end`.

Answer (score 2):

**Two problems:**

1. You need to change `i <= end` to `i >= end`.
2. `String` is an immutable object in Java (cannot change after construction).

   You need to use `StringBuilder` instead, and convert it into `String` when done.

**So your code should look something like this:**

```
StringBuilder countD = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = start; i >= end; i = i - increment)
    countD.append(i).append(" ");
return countD.toString();
```

Comment: `countD.append(i+" ");` will create another StringBuilder to concatenate `i` and `" "`. To avoid it use `countD.append(i).append(" ");`

Comment: Are you suggesting that `i+" "` returns a `StringBuilder`??? I doubt that very much.

Comment: I mean that `i+" "` is compiled to use `new StringBuilder(i).append(" ").toString()`. We don't use StringBuilder in loops because strings are immutable, but to avoid creating in each instance new Strings which will be results of such concatenation. Creating StringBuilder before loop and appending to it chunks of data solves this problem.

Comment: I don't think so. `i+" "` is compiled as a new (temporary) `String` instance. Then, method `append` of class `StringBuilder` is called with this `String` instance. Apart from the initial `StringBuilder` instance, no other `StringBuilder` instance is created here.

Comment: Compiler can't know value of `i` at compilation time so concatenation must be done at runtime, that is why it is compiled to use another StringBuilder.

Comment: You don't have to believe me. Test it yourself. Decompile code with `sb.append(i+" ")` to see that `StringBuilder."<init>` (constructor) will be put in code at least two times: once for `sb`, and once for `i+" "`. To decompile class you can use `javap -c ClassWithYourCode`.

Comment: `i+" "` does not cause the creation of a `StringBuilder` instance. Try this: `int i; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`. If you write `String str1 = sb;` then you'll get a compilation error. If you write `String str2 = i+" ";`, then you won't. A direct assignment `String a = (StringBuilder)b` is not possible. `i+" "` is a `String` and not a `StringBuilder`!!!

Comment: I am not saying that `i+" "` will **return** instance of StringBuilder but it will **use** it to create new String. This expression will be compiled to create new StringBuilder which will be initialized with first concatenation argument (`i`) and later will append `" "` to it. After this it will return String which will be result of this concatenation. In short `new StringBuilder(i).append(" ").toString()`. Notice that last method is `toString()` which means this expression will return `String`, not `StringBuilder`

Comment: So what exactly is the advantage of `countD.append(i).append(" ")` over `countD.append(i+" ")`, or what is the exactly difference between them?

Comment: Advantage is that you will not create another temporary object (instance of another StringBuilder) in each loop iteration. This way only one instance will be used (the one created before loop).

Comment: OK, gotcha. Thanks for enlightening me (been using this method quite often).

Comment: No problem. Feel free to edit your answer then so I could see that this discussion was not in vain :)

Comment: I just have to ask: So is `countD.append(i+" ")` an equivalent of `countD.append(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(i)).append(" ").toString())`?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Done. But I (also) have to ask - wouldn't `countD.append(i)` have the same effect of creating a temporary `StringBuilder` object?

Comment: No. Argument you pass to append doesn't require separate concatenating so new StringBuilder will not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the condition `i <= end`, if you're starting from a higher number, it should be the other way around, then it all works nicely.